# Java class not used as a COM object from classic ASP page

Tags: java, windows, iis, asp-classic, com

I am stuck in a very strange problem for which i haven't found a solution from Internet as yet.Here is my issue:-

I have a pre-compiled java class which is registered with javareg utility so that it can be used as a COM object in classic ASP page. Thus, this java class is called in global.asa with a Prog ID and then it is used all over the page to call it's methods. This is working well in our current development server which is Windows Server 2003 R2.But, it is not working in our new 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have done the registration using javareg but when i try to create an object using Server.CreateObject in ASP page, i am getting "ASP 0177 : 80070002' Server.CreateObject Failed." Thus, i tried to create a sample java class in our existing development server and registered it using javareg and used Server.CreateObject to instantiate it but even i am getting this same error in Dev server, which proves i am even not able to use a java class as COM object even in the working dev server. Also, when i tried to simulate the CreateObject method using Vb 6, i am now getting a Classfactory automation error.

So what can be the issue? I see the id which i logged on to the server has been added to Administrators group, thus there is faint chance of any permission problem. Also, i see the registered java COM components present in Control Panel->Components...Any suggestions or help is truly appreciated...

Additional info:-

Existing dev server specs:

Windows Server 2003 R2(32 bit)

IIS 6.0

.Net Framework 2.0

New server specs:

Windows Server 2008 R2(64 bit)

IIS 7.5

.Net Framework 3.5

Comment: What is your command to register?  Try this and see if you get the same results, http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0044.html as in do their class and so on, not yours.

Comment: Is the application pool (your web application is using) set to use `Enable 32 Bit Applications` set to `True` in advanced settings?

Comment: javareg /register /class:abc.class /progid:abc
trustlib directory is already present in C:\windows\java...Thus, i did this one:-
copy abc.class c:\windows\java\trustlib\abc.class

Comment: Also, enable 32 app is set to true in IIS

Comment: Have you tried the opposite? `Enable 32 Bit Applications` set to `False` it's possible `javareg` maybe the 64 bit app and has inadvertently registered the ProgId into the 64 bit class registry.

Comment: Yes tried everything..But Lanky tell me one thing...Let's forget the 64 bit server..in 32 bit existing dev server, why can't i call a sample abc.class as COM from ASP page using server.createobject..At this line, error is throwing...BUt in the same server, that xyz.class is working perfectly fine as COM(This xyz.class was existing from the beginning..so i have no idea how those people really made a COM out of this...

Comment: Sorry, you lost me a bit there. Are you saying *your* object `abc.class` doesn't work on the 32 bit environment as well?

Comment: Let me explain...xyz.class is working fine in 32 bit server...in this server, i tried to create a sample abc.class using javac command and getting error in Server.CreateObject after registering with javareg.why? Now, if this problem is solved, i can be sure that in 64 bit environment also this solution will work out the same.

Comment: I would check in `regedit` that your ProgId appears in the list under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes` sub key, if it's there then the COM object is registered properly (on a 64 bit server the 32 bit location is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes`).

Comment: Yes that is present and so i guess it is registered properly...

Comment: If it is registered it's possibly a permissions issue that is causing the `Server.CreateObject Failed` error. Found this article very useful in the past - [PRB: Server Object Error 'ASP 0177:80040154' Server.CreateObject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175804).

Comment: I have tried adding any possible permissions but to no luck! Just asking can this pre-existing working java class(abc.class) compiled in jvc instead of javac? And this test xyz.class i have compiled in javac and so it's not working? if that is so, i don't know how to compile in JVC because it's not installed in dev server i guess. any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved now after an in-depth analysis which I would like to share...We had to convert the java class into a C#.net dll and register it with regasm tool. Now, we had to make a few changes in the calling methods of ASP page which calls the functions of dll. It works now after eliminating the COM dependency!!!